# Replace cell values in specific sheets with defined name

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I am trying to run some code that replaces the cell values in a specific column with a defined name. In addition, I have a condition that the replacement should only take place if the first 9 characters of the values are `xxxxxxxxx`.

More precisely, it should change the values in `C:C` in 2 specific worksheets (I don't want to loop through the whole workbook).

I am not sure why nothing happens in the code (no error messages, nothing).

I presume, however, that I should not use `With` if I want the code to work in these 2 specific worksheets. I am also aware that my use of `Range` is probably not totally correct.

```
Sub ChangeMe()

  Dim cl As Range

  For Each cl In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C").End(xlUp)
    With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C:C").End(xlUp)
      If Left(cl.Value, 9) = "XXXXXXXXX" Then
        cl.Value = ThisWorkbook.Names("MyDefinedName").RefersToRange
      End If
    End With
  Next cl

End Sub
```

Comment: read your post several times, still not sure what you are trying to acomplish. Can you explain where is `"XXXXXXX"` located ? which column at which sheet ? once it's found, what value you want it replaced with ?

Comment: Have you tried assigning a different value to `cl.Value` in your `If` statement, such as `1` or `test`?  Same results?

Comment: Your code will replace the contents of `cl` with the contents of the cell referred to by `MyDefinedName`, **so long as `RefersToRange` is a single cell.**  If `MyDefinedName` refers to multiple cells, then perhaps `...RefersToRange(1,1)` might be more appropriate.  But without more information, hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

In answer your original questions:

> I am not sure why nothing happens in the code (no error messages, nothing).

Nothing happens because your worksheet values are *lowercase* `xxxxxxxxx`, whilst your code checks for *uppercase* `XXXXXXXXX`.

> I presume, however, that I should not use `With` if I want the code to work in these 2 specific worksheets.

Actually, you *can* use `With` with multiple sheets, as I will demonstrate below.

> I am also aware that my use of `Range` is probably not totally correct.

That is true. If you were to fix the uppercase issue, only `C1` would be changed. This is because `.End()` works on a single cell. If you supply a multi-cell range, it uses the top left most cell. So `.Range("C:C").End(xlUp)` is equivalent to `.Range("C1").End(xlUp)` which evaluates to just `C1`.

---

The following will answer your updated question:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ChangeMe()

  Const l_xxxxxxxxx      As String = "xxxxxxxxx"
  Const l_MyDefinedName  As String = "MyDefinedName"
  Const s_Delimiter      As String = ","
  Const s_WorkSheetNames As String = "Sheet1,Sheet2"
  Const s_ColumnToChange As String = "C:C"

  Dim varWorkSheetName As Variant
  For Each varWorkSheetName In Split(s_WorkSheetNames, s_Delimiter)
    With Worksheets(varWorkSheetName).Range(s_ColumnToChange)
      Dim rngCell As Range
      For Each rngCell In .Resize(.Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        With rngCell
          Dim strCellValue As String: strCellValue = .Value2
          If Left(strCellValue, Len(l_xxxxxxxxx)) = l_xxxxxxxxx Then
            .Value2 _
            = Names(l_MyDefinedName).RefersToRange.Value2 _
            & Right$(strCellValue, Len(strCellValue) - Len(l_xxxxxxxxx))
          End If
        End With
      Next rngCell
    End With
  Next varWorkSheetName

End Sub
```

Notes:

- It is a good idea to use constants so all literal values are typed once only and kept grouped together.
- Using `.Value2`, instead of `.Value`, is the recommended way to access a cell's value as it avoids implicit casting and is therefore faster. (Using `.Value` can also sometimes cause issues.)
- Surprisingly, in VBA there are good reasons to put a variable declaration as close as possible to the first use of the variable. Two such reasons are 1) it improves readability, and 2) it simplifies future refactoring. Just remember that the variable is not reinitialised every time the `Dim` is encountered. Initialisation only occurs the first time.

Comment: Thank you RobinCTS. This code hists the nail on the head - runs excellent. Thank you for the tips as well. They are very helpful and will definitely make use of them in future

Comment: @Dozens Don't forget to accept the best answer (by clicking on the grey tick at the top left of the answer), and to upvote any/every useful answer (by clicking the "up" triangle).

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine that this is your input:

[image]

In this case, you want to change the values in range `A1:A2` to the value in `C1` (named range xxxx123), because it starts with `xxxx123`. This is the code to achieve it:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myCell          As Range
    Dim myNamedRange    As String

    myNamedRange = "xxxx123"

    For Each myCell In Range("A1:A2")
        If Left(myCell, Len(myNamedRange)) = myNamedRange Then
            myCell.Value = Range(myNamedRange)
        End If
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your post correctly (which I doubt it), I think you want to loop through column "C" in both "Sheet1" and "Sheet2". Every cell that starts with 9 `"XXXXXXXXX"`, should be replaced with the value in `"MyDefinedName"` Named Range.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeMe()

Dim cl As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    With sht
        If .Name = "Sheet1" Or .Name = "Sheet2" Then
            For Each cl In .Range("C1:C" & .Cells(.rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
                If Left(cl.Value, 9) = "XXXXXXXXX" Then
                    cl.Value = ThisWorkbook.Names("MyDefinedName").RefersToRange
                End If
            Next cl
        End If
    End With
Next sht

End Sub
```